# Java class version is displayed incorrectly

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, jar

I want to run the jar file distributed by eclipse in the terminal.
I entered the command in the terminal like this.

```
java -jar test.jar
```

And an error occurred.

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
project01/test01 has been compiled by a more recent version of the 
Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java 
Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

The error says my Java class version is 59, but I installed **jdk1.8.0_281.jdk**
Then I can't understand the error because my version is 52.

Is there a solution?
I'm using macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse compiled class files that can be run with JDK15 or higher (that's what 59.0 means). Therefore, it won't run on the JDK1.8 you installed.

Tell eclipse to compile to a lower version (which will not work, unless you use no features introduced since jdk8), or run the jar on JDK15+.

You can configure this by right clicking on your project, picking properties, and looking around there.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are compiling your Program with a newer version of JAVA.
And trying to run it with an older version.

You have to understand that java comes with **JRE**, which is the Java Runtime Environment.
This is the environment where all java programs are run. It's like a virtual machine.

Then **JDK** comes, which is the Java Development Kit, here you can create and compile java programs. The compiler and the runner (JDK & JRE) have to be compatible with each other.

You should also check which version is Eclipse using by :

Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Configuration tab. Locate the line that says: `java.runtime.version=....`